# Margins of wpf button are highlighted on mouseover

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers

I'm new to WPF and i have small issue. I have a button with XAML:

```
<Button  FontSize="17" Margin="15" Background="White" 
         BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="#f6f6f6"
         FontWeight="DemiBold"
                   fluent:KeyTip.Keys="X"
                   CommandParameter="{Binding}"                                                               
                   Click="OnLoadPluginClick">                                                
    <Button.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect Opacity="0.15"/>
    </Button.Effect>                                                
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Border Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1"
                    Grid.Row="0" Margin="5,10,0,0"  Height="180" Width="180" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                <Grid Height="180" Width="180" >
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Margin="10,10,0,0" FontSize="15" FontStretch="ExtraCondensed" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <Image Stretch="Uniform" Width="70" Height="70" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
               VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="{Binding ImageSource}" />
                </Grid>
            </Border>

            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Button.IsPressed" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="WhiteSmoke" />

                </Trigger>                                                            
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Effect">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" Color="WhiteSmoke" Opacity="0.6" BlurRadius="20"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <!--<Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"></Setter>-->
                </Trigger>                                                            
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

As you can see i have my own triggers, but i can't the appeareance i want (shadows when mouse is on button). I get something like this:

[image: WrongMarginHighlight]

as you can see, i have only my margins highlighted with akward gray color...

What i need: when mouse is on button border, the border gets bigger shadow, when border is pressed, it's background is set to WhiteSmoke

Something like this, but with image:
[image: cancelButton]

How can i implement this button correctly?

I'll be gratefull for any help.

Comment: Do you have an image of what you're trying to accomplish to help visualize your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Set TargetName=Border in the setter tag of IsMouseOver Trigger. It may work..

Comment: This doesn't help, i still get that awk square :(